# Excel - Compare one column to another and display results

Tags: function, excel, excel-formula, vba

In Excel 2007, I have two columns, similar data (list of names). If the name is found in both columns I'd like to change a blank column to active. How can this be done?

Longer Description of what I'd like to do:

Column A:A on Sheet 1 has 300 names. Column A:A on Sheet 2 has 20 names. If the names on Sheet 2 are also in Sheet 1 I'd like to fill Column A:B on Sheet 1 with the word "Active"

How can this be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you had the names in Column A of both sheets, In cell B1 of Sheet1, put in the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Active","Not Active")
```

You can then drag that formula down - If the name exists in BOTH, it will say "Active" otherwise it will say "Not Active".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Stewbob had a correct answer, but this answer gave me more options and I went with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled with a simple `VLOOKUP` formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE)=A1,"Active","")
```

The above formula is placed in cell B1 on Sheet1 and then copied down as far as there is data in column A on sheet 1.

The only caveat with this formula is that the data in Sheet2 column A must be sorted alphabetically.

The `FALSE` near the end of the formula indicates that an exact match is required.

Comment: After a little bit of fumbling (not tweaking, I never changed your method, I just didn't apply it correctly) this worked. Thanks.